# Random Number Generator

Tags: iphone, objective-c

```
- (IBAction)randomnum{
int randomNumber1 = 1+ arc4random() %(49);
label1.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"d", randomNumber];
```

**Warning:**

> Local declaration of randomNumber hides instance variable.

How can i get round this warning?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2560980/looking-for-a-clear-and-concise-web-page-explaining-why-lower-bits-of-random-numb

Comment: Is the `1` in `randomNumber1` intentional or a typo?

Comment: @Hamish, how is that a dup of this question?

Comment: It is not a dupe of the question.

Answer (score 4):

You had some instance variable of the class with the same name of your randomNumber1 or randomNumber. Recheck for that and change the name, you would be fine